# Printing hexadecimals using write()

Tags: c, system-calls

I am learning about system calls and one thing I want to learn is formatting using write(). I couldn't search up much information about write() system call regarding printing in different formats.

I have a function that prints an array in either decimal or hexadecimal format. However, I would like to convert it such that it uses write().

```
if (hexFlag == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                    fprintf(fp, "%d ", array[i]);
            }
    } else {
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                    fprintf(fp, "%x ", array[i]);
            }
    }
```

I know how to use write() to print basic decimals, but I cannot find any information on printing in hexadecimals.

Comment: `write()` doesn't deal with formats, it just writes whatever is in the buffer. Use `sprintf()` to put hex into the buffer, then call `write()` on that.

Comment: What is the type of `array`?

Answer (score 2):

`write()` just "prints" raw memory contents - there's no way to set any formatting there. Your only option is to preformat the buffer (for example using `sprintf()` or things like that) and then use `write()`.

Answer (score 1):

Write system call will throw everything that is in the buffer to the file provided by file descriptor. You will have to construct the buffer string with hex values and then pass it to write system call. Here is what you can do:

```
 char buf[3] = {0};
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    snprintf(buf, 2, "%02x ", array[i]);
    write(fd, buf, 2);
 }
```

Comment: Hello, somehow the file that this printed to is telling me that it is a binary file.

Comment: Have you obtained file descriptor from file stream? How have you opened the file?